# Error reporting within MYSQLi for unknown index

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm attempting to call a function to update my mysqli db, and report back if an error happened. I have this in my test file so far:

```
<?php

$success = test("cat",17);
echo $success;
echo "<br />";


function test($name, $number){
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
    if($db->connect_errno){
        return "Failed to connect to MYSQL Database: [" . $db->connect_errorno . "]" . $db->connect_error;
    }
    if(!($stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `test` SET `name` = ? WHERE `number` = ?"))){
        return "prepare failed: [" . $db->errno . "]" . $db->error;
    }
    if(!($stmt->bind_param('si', $name, $number))){
        return "bind failed: [" . $db->errno . "]" . $db->error;
    }
    if(!($stmt->execute())){
        return "execute failed: [" . $db->errno . "]" . $db->error;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return "Successfully updated database!";
}

?>
```

and with the test I have there (cat, 17) it returns a success, even though there is no column with a number of 17, and I see nothing change in the database. How can I get it to properly return a failure if it cannot find the number in the WHERE clause?

Comment: a query which doesn't change any records, or doesn't return any rows, is **NOT** a "failure". it's simply an empty result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `execute()` completes, check that `$stmt->affected_rows` is greater than zero:

```
if(!($stmt->execute())){
    return "execute failed: [" . $db->errno . "]" . $db->error;
}

if(!$stmt->affected_rows) {
    return "no rows updated";
}
```